# Getting exception on retriving data for the second time using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Sir I have filled my dataset with linq as

```
 public void FillDataSet(DataSet ds1,int Id)
   {
       try
       {
           var y = from ins in cstmrDC.customers_rd(Id) select ins;
           var z = from ins in cstmrDC.customersCntcts_rd(Id) select ins;

           DataTable dtCst = new DataTable("dtCstmr");
           dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_Id");
           dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_Name");
           dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_SName");
           dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_AdLn1");

           DataTable dtDtls = new DataTable("dtDtails");
           dtDtls.Columns.Add("cst_SrlNo");
           dtDtls.Columns.Add("cst_CntName");
           dtDtls.Columns.Add("cst_cntDsgn");


           foreach (var dtbl in y)
           {
               DataRow dr;
               dr = dtCst.NewRow();
               dr[0] = dtbl.cust_Id;
               dr[1] = dtbl.cust_Name;
               dr[2] = dtbl.cust_Sname;
               dr[3] = dtbl.cust_Adrsln1;
               dtCst.Rows.Add(dr);

           }
           foreach (var dtbl in z)
           {
               DataRow drDtls;
               drDtls = dtDtls.NewRow();
               drDtls[0] = dtbl.cust_Slno;
               drDtls[1] = dtbl.cust_Cntctnm;
               drDtls[2] = dtbl.cust_Cntctdesig;          
               dtDtls.Rows.Add(drDtls);
           }

           ds1.Tables.Add(dtCst);
           ds1.Tables.Add(dtDtls);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

and the Id is passing from another class as

```
            intId = int.Parse(txtSearch.Text);
            cstCls.FillDataSet(ds1w, intId);
```

from that dataset iam fillimg my textbox controllers and giving theDataSource to the dataGridView as 
`dgvCustInfo.DataSource = ds1w.Tables["dtDtails"];`

In this way if I searched 1st time with integer id 1055 meanse the exact result is comming from database. At the same time If I gave the another integer Id as 1066 meance Iam getting exception as `DataTable named 'dtCstmr' already belongs to this DataSet` .. Soo how can I solve the problem.

Comment: what I want to say, you must improve with naming variables, those variable names really giving me headache when trying to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a table is already contained in a `DataSet` with [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye3t49b6.aspx):

```
if(!ds1.Tables.Contains(dtCst.TableName))
    ds1.Tables.Add(dtCst);
if(!ds1.Tables.Contains(dtDtls.TableName))
    ds1.Tables.Add(dtDtls);
```

However, as Raphael has mentioned this would not refresh the table in the DataSet. So an easy way would be to remove the old table and add the new:

```
if(ds1.Tables.Contains(dtCst.TableName))
    ds1.Tables.Remove(dtCst.TableName);
if(ds1.Tables.Contains(dtDtls.TableName))
    ds1.Tables.Remove(dtDtls.TableName);
ds1.Tables.Add(dtCst);
ds1.Tables.Add(dtDtls);
```

Comment: It will remove the error, but  all assignments done in the method will be useless : new Datatables filled with data won't be used anymore. I just mean that all the method should use the logic "if DataTable not exists then create it (and add Columns), other way get DataTable from DataSet.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: You're right. Edited my answer to take that into account. There might be a better way though.

Comment: Now +1 ;) But indeed, the code structure is bad : why the hell are the DataTables dtCst and dtDtls defined in this method ? This is confusing. That should be done on another place in the class.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: You are right sir.. it removing only error. Not helpful to retrive data again with different Id.

Comment: @NareshJ: You have noticed that i've added a different approach with removing the tables first? You should not need to pass a DataSet to this method. It should return it. Btw, what does `cstmrDC.customers_rd(Id)` return?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: That returns one record based on Id and cstmrDC.customersCntcts_rd(Id) returns multiple records based on same Id sir...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a bad idea to create and populate in the same method.

Your code is really confusing.

Create another method :

```
public void CreateTables(DataSet ds1) {
  var dtCst = new DataTable("dtCstmr");
  dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_Id");
  dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_Name");
  dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_SName");
  dtCst.Columns.Add("cst_AdLn1");

  var dtDtls = new DataTable("dtDtails");
  dtDtls.Columns.Add("cst_SrlNo");
  dtDtls.Columns.Add("cst_CntName");
  dtDtls.Columns.Add("cst_cntDsgn");

  ds1.Tables.Add(dtCst);
  ds1.Tables.Add(dtDtls);
}

public void FillDataSet(DataSet ds1,int Id)
   {
       try
       {
           var y = from ins in cstmrDC.customers_rd(Id) select ins;
           var z = from ins in cstmrDC.customersCntcts_rd(Id) select ins;

           var dtCst = ds1.Tables["dtCstmr"];
           var dtDtls = ds1.Tables["dtDtails"];
           dtCst.Clear();
           dtDtls.Clear();


           foreach (var dtbl in y)
           {
               DataRow dr;
               dr = dtCst.NewRow();
               dr[0] = dtbl.cust_Id;
               dr[1] = dtbl.cust_Name;
               dr[2] = dtbl.cust_Sname;
               dr[3] = dtbl.cust_Adrsln1;
               dtCst.Rows.Add(dr);

           }
           foreach (var dtbl in z)
           {
               DataRow drDtls;
               drDtls = dtDtls.NewRow();
               drDtls[0] = dtbl.cust_Slno;
               drDtls[1] = dtbl.cust_Cntctnm;
               drDtls[2] = dtbl.cust_Cntctdesig;          
               dtDtls.Rows.Add(drDtls);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

Method `CreateTables` should be called only one time, and `FillDataSet` as many times as needed.

Comment: then When should i call the method CreateTables(DataSet ds1);
without calling the method how can i create the dataTable

Comment: @NareshJ well, I would say, when you instanciate your DataSet... But I don't know your class structure.